# Install attempt of Boilerpipe-py3 gives 404 error

Tags: python, version, boilerpipe

Boilerpipe is a great Java program for cleaning web pages and I've used it in the past. I note today that many users are not able to install the Python wrapper version and get 404 and other errors. Here is one of my attempts which I copied from conda.

/Users/duncan>sudo -H pip install https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/b/boilerpipe-py3/boilerpipe-py3-1.2.0.0.tar.gz
Collecting https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/b/boilerpipe-py3/boilerpipe-py3-1.2.0.0.tar.gz
  Downloading boilerpipe-py3-1.2.0.0.tar.gz (1.3MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.3MB 436kB/s 
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "", line 1, in 
      File "/tmp/pip-r6swd0hy-build/setup.py", line 33, in 
        download_jars(datapath=DATAPATH)
      File "/tmp/pip-r6swd0hy-build/setup.py", line 26, in download_jars
        urlretrieve(tgz_url, tgz_name)
      File "/Users/duncan/anaconda/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 188, in urlretrieve
        with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:
      File "/Users/duncan/anaconda/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 163, in urlopen
        return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
      File "/Users/duncan/anaconda/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 472, in open
        response = meth(req, response)
      File "/Users/duncan/anaconda/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 582, in http_response
        'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
      File "/Users/duncan/anaconda/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 510, in error
        return self._call_chain(*args)
      File "/Users/duncan/anaconda/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 444, in _call_chain
        result = func(*args)
      File "/Users/duncan/anaconda/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 590, in http_error_default
        raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
    urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found

```
----------------------------------------
```

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-r6swd0hy-build/

I've seen several solutions that didn't work for me (ex: google changed its URL for a module) If anyone has a solution I would be very grateful!

My platform here is a 16GB El Capitan but I've seen this reported on Ubuntu and other platforms. Thank you for any help here!

Answer (score 1):

I just forking and re-download the [boilerpipe-1.2.0-bin.tar.gz](https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/boilerpipe/boilerpipe-1.2.0-bin.tar.gz) from here [code.google.com](https://code.google.com/archive/p/boilerpipe/downloads) into my repository here https://github.com/slaveofcode/boilerpipe3

you can install boilerpipe by using pip

```
pip install boilerpipe3
```

or by project repository

```
pip install git+ssh://git@github.com/slaveofcode/boilerpipe3@master
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, it is because boilerpipe URL has been moved. I worked around it by changing this line in setup.py inside the installation tar.gz from pypi:

Old line:
`tgz_url = 'https://boilerpipe.googlecode.com/files/boilerpipe-{0}-bin.tar.gz'.format(version)`

New line:
**`tgz_url = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/boilerpipe/boilerpipe-{0}-bin.tar.gz'.format(version)`**

Re-compress the entire folder and run pip install on the new compressed directory.